# Using a session-specific .vimrc

Tags: vim, vimrc, csh

I share accounts with other developers for test environments. The `.vimrc` on some of these accounts sets rows and columns, changing my terminal size, which drives me nuts.

Is there a way I can set a temporary, "session-specific" `.vimrc`?

I imagine it being used like

```
% source ~acheong/.vimrc
```

and then all subsequent `vim` instances in that session using this personal `.vimrc`. (But of course, the above won't work.)

Comment: I know it may not be worth the effort to convince your coworkers, but for what it's worth, .vimrc should never change the 'rows' or 'columns' options. It _might_ be excusable in .gvimrc, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start vim with a configuration file other than ~/.vimrc by using the `-u` option like this:

```
vim -N -u ~acheong/.vimrc
```

To avoid typing that each time, you could define an alias for it each time you log in to one of those accounts:

```
alias vim='vim -N -u ~acheong/.vimrc'
```

See

```
:help -u
:help initialization
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the complete answer that solved my issue. Also, I didn't know about the ``-N`` flag; useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-u` option to pass in a temporary `.vimrc` that will override the default. From the [`man`](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/vim.1.php):

> -u {vimrc}
>
> Use the commands in the file {vimrc} for initializations. All the
>   other initializations are skipped. Use this to edit a special kind of
>   files. It can also be used to skip all initializations by giving the
>   name "NONE". See ":help initialization" within vim for more details.

i.e: `vim -u ~acheong/myvimrc`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you searching for the `so` command ?

Moreover, how are you connecting to the shared session ? In case of a sudo, you can for instance use `so ~$SUDO_USER/.vimrc`.

Comment: This is possibly the most difficult command to Google, ever. My system doesn't have a command called ``so`` and I can't find any references to ``so`` online; could you elaborate? I'm using PuTTY/SSH and our standard shell is ``csh`` (and yes it makes me want to die).